# Interactive maven archetype catalog

Tags: java, maven

I'm creating a maven plugin and I want to allow user to create a project by specifying some details required by my plugin.
I understand that when creating a project with simple **mvn archetype:generate**
it points to the maven default archtype catalog which asks for groupId, artifactId, etc.

The question here is how do I create my own custom catalog so that I can make creation of a project interactive for the customer.

e.g. When a client points to my archetype catalog like

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://abc.com/archetype-catalog.xml
```

he should be able to see the following,

```
Define value for project_home: C:/XYZ
Define value for server-url: http://localhost:8080/
Define value for groupId: : com.xyz
Define value for artifactId: : sample
Define value for version:  1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for package:  com.xyz
Confirm properties configuration:
project-home: C:/XYZ
server-url: http://localhost:8080/
groupId: com.xyz
artifactId: sample
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.xyz
 Y: :
```

Any pointer or some link on web would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I've viewed pustefix-archetype-basic as an example, and there is in the META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml following code:

```
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="groupId">
      <defaultValue>mytld.myorg</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="artifactId">
      <defaultValue>myapp</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="version">
      <defaultValue>1.0-SNAPSHOT</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="package">
      <defaultValue>mytld.myorg.myapp</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
    <requiredProperty key="pustefixVersion">
      <defaultValue>0.18.30</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
```

Try to add your properties :)